# Angular 2.0 with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular

I am upgrading an application which heavily uses ui-router.

I am trying to upgrade a directive which has a `ui-view` in its template (to be an Angular 2 Component using the `UpgradeAdapter`).

It does not work.. (I guess that Angular 2.0 is not working with the ui-router, yet?). Am I right? Do we know when ui-router be Angular 2.0 ready?

Should I upgrade my ui-router and use the new Angular 2 router? This is not straight forward upgrade because I heavily use the `resolve` feature, which is not supported in the new router!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [some hints](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1759#issuecomment-170984733) that it will happen sooner or later. Probably not on the day of 2.0 release.

Currently UI Router [can be used in 1.x application](https://github.com/ngUpgraders/ng-forward/issues/42#issuecomment-151701572) until [component router](https://github.com/ngUpgraders/ng-forward/issues/100) or [uniform UI Router](https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/42hvc2/uirouter_0216_released/czafrol) will come up.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I've just managed to do this. Here's an example hybrid application in the process of being upgraded from NG1 to NG2, with both versions of UI router: https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app/tree/hybrid-angular1-angular2